# jquery validation - remote method - json

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-validate

Using jQuery validation plugin -

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Wanting to use the remote method on a field (username) to check if the username is unique (response is in a json format - cannot use php). So, all of the remote methods I see use php with a function for processing within the php file. Obviously, with json, I can't do that.

So using "remote", how would I check uniqueness from a json response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `response` is evaluated as JSON and must be `true` for valid elements, and can be any `false`, `undefined` or `null` for invalid elements.

Make use of plugin like this:

```
$("#your_form").validate({
  rules: {
    username: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: "check_username.php"
      // or other server side script 
      // or JSON response (must be boolean) 

    }
  }
});
```

Above code will makes the `username` field required, an username and does a remote request to check if the given username is already taken.

Comment: cannot use php - see question - trying to get this to work with json

Comment: Hello Jason--as you're checking in database for uniqueness of username, then you must do it through a server-side programming language, here it is PHP I've mentioned. In that file, you should perform a SELECT query on database, and check for username uniqueness and on the basis of that, return or echo `true` or `false`. This response is evaluated as JSON by jQuery validation plugin.

Comment: right - edit your answer and I can remove the downvote. sorry.

Comment: hey Vishal - see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707981/jquery-validation-remote-method-error-message-in-json-response - trying to pull the error message out of the json response

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm missing something from your question but your remote validation method should return `true` or `false`, that's all. The validation plugin takes care of the rest.