# jquery validation - addMethod/remote - error message in json response

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-validate

I'm trying to either use the remote method, or add a method that mimics the remote method to be able to send the entered data to a web service and get a json response back with the error state and error message.

so I have this json response:

```
{
    "isError": "true",
    "errorMessage": "The User Name you chose is already in use. Please enter another name."
}
```

I've used the remote method to get a true/false response, but not with extra data.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

Tried this, but of course it didn't work because the variable is not a global variable...

```
$.validator.addMethod("uniqueUserName", function(value, element) {

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         url: "js/username.json",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
        dataType:"json",
        data: "{'" + $('#enterEmail').attr('id') + "': '" + $('#enterEmail').val() + "'}", 
        dataFilter: function(data) {
            var isError = data.isError;
            var uniqueError = data.errorMessage;
            if(isError == "true"){
                return false;
            }
        }

     })

}, uniqueError); //this last line would typically be: }, "my error message");
```

see fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jasonday/fWk5u/

Comment: do you want extra data returned in your JSON response? I think this would have to be done server-side/web-service side unless you want to map "true/false" to some other variable in your success/error handler. Not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @frequent - yeah, I edited the last line of the `addMethod` function to show where the error message usually goes - a text string. But I want to pass the json value of `errorMessage` there.

Comment: ok. so are you getting back a JSON response as in your first snippet or do you want to show the error message if JSON returns false? Also see my EDIT below

Comment: this is a mockup, the actual url will be to a web service which returns a json response. I want the error messaging to be handled the same way (in conjunction with) jquery validate. I could dummy it by writing it the same way to the DOM as the plugin, but I would rather integrate.

Comment: Can you modify the response from the server? If you just return a string, jQuery Validate will assume it is the error message, so there's really no need to return both the error message and a boolean representing the success or failure of the validation

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - see below for what I needed to do.

Comment: @Jason: I'm not sure what you mean (below where.. in the answer?), but if you mean setting `async: false` on your AJAX request, I would highly recommend against that. You are making a synchronous call that will block the entire browser for the duration of said call.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - sorry - forgot to post my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. The return success is what I was failing - I kept returning, returning true, or returning false - and every one of them would "fail" validation.

```
remote: {
    type: "POST",
    url: "js/username.json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
    dataType:"json",
    data: "{'" + $('#enterEmail').attr('id') + "': '" + $('#enterEmail').val() + "'}",
    dataFilter: function(data) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        if(json.isError == "true") {
            return "\"" + json.errorMessage + "\"";
        } else {
            return success;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the "success"(variable or function)? I have the similar problem wether I return true/false, validation always said please fix this. dataFilter supposed to work? If so what version of validation plugin you are using?

Comment: Bro, I love you! In 2019 the problem was in that I need WRAP in double quotes message '"' + 'Carl wtf' + '"'. OMG it's so simple but so hart to find ))

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [validval](http://validval.frebsite.nl/usage.php).

I found it fairly easy to integrate, tweak (custom validations, custom alerts), plus fiddle it into AJAX like [here](http://validval.frebsite.nl/examples.php)

**EDIT**
So where are you posting your data object to? What does **js/username.json** do? 
If you post there you have to do something there to return the object in your desired format.

So if you want to check for unique email, I'm posting to the server, do a check there, construct an object

```
 object.response.success = true/false
 object.response.data = "some text to display"
```

and then return the object.response via AJAX.

Like so:

```
 $.ajax({
      async: false,
      type: "post",
      url: "somewhere_to_handle_username_check",    
      data: data: "{'" + $('#enterEmail').attr('id') + "': '" + $('#enterEmail').val() + "'}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      // AJAX OK, return true/false
      success: function(objResponse){
           if (objResponse = "true"){
                alert("success");
            } else {
                alert("failed, username already taken");
            }
      // AJAX Failed
      error: function () { 
        alert("failed - AJAX failed");
        }
    });
```

I'm usually validating client side, that an email address was entered (using above validaval) and then send the email adress to the server for checking the value and constructing the response object.

Hope this helps. If not, let me know what your AJAX request should do and what js/username.json does.

Comment: that doesn't really answer my question.